# Issues using pt-kill to kill log queries

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I'm trying to get `pt-kill` to work to kill queries running longer than *n*.

The command as I'm running now is;

```
pt-kill --busy-time 15 --print -u root -p `cat mysqlpw` --victims all --log /var/log/pt-kill.log --match-all
```

The problem is that I'm seeing lots of queries under 15 seconds being logged;

```
# 2016-08-06T20:29:34 KILL 187563 (Sleep 1 sec) NULL
# 2016-08-06T20:29:34 KILL 204826 (Sleep 0 sec) NULL
# 2016-08-06T20:29:34 KILL 204819 (Execute 0 sec) SELECT <snip>
```

Obviously I have no intention of killing these queries, so i haven't been able to actually use this in anger yet.

Am I missing something in the args? Maybe its an issue with Maria10.1? I'd love to be able to use this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
pt-kill --busy-time 15 --print -u root -p password --match-command Query --victims all
```

Then add `--kill-query` if you think this one is what you intend to use.

**Edit**

Changed `--match-all` to `--victims all`

Comment: Hi @jerichorivera, I tried Query, Execute and Sleep. I also tried match-all. It keeps including queries that are 0 seconds long.

Comment: Can you show what queries you are running and which ones you want to have killed by pt-kill?